# Find the prime factors of an integer

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int integer;
        int num = 2;//a number to be tested for primeness
        int count = 0;//count the number of prime numbers

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        integer = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (count <= integer) {
            boolean isPrime = true;//is current number prime
            //test wether number is prime

            for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
                if (num % i == 0) {//if true number is not prime
                    isPrime = false;//set is prime to false
                    break;//exit the loop
                }
            }

            if (isPrime) {
                count++;
                System.out.print(num);
            }

            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi I need this program to just print the smallest factors of an integer e.g If the in put is 60 give an output of 2,3,5. It does that but it also adds a lot of other ascending prime factors. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please format code & add better description for help.

Comment: When you say smallest factors, how small do you want it? And how many?

Comment: ...how many other prime factors does 60 have?

Comment: Why don't you use a basic factorization method like Fermat? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method

Comment: I havnt learned the method Fermat. I needed to use what i have learned!

Answer (score 3):

Your loop condition is meant to print first 'x' prime numbers so if you enter 60 it will print first 60 prime numbers. That is 2,3,5,7,11 ...

Please modify your code like this to get desired output (just replace the entire loop)

```
while (num <= integer) { //Changed the condition here to 
        //stop when the number reached integer and not count 
        boolean isPrime = true;//is current number prime
        //test wether number is prime

        for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {//if true number is not prime
                isPrime = false;//set is prime to false
                break;//exit the loop
            }
        }
        if (isPrime && integer % num == 0) {// added an additional check that
        // print the number only if it is prime and 
        // it is divides the integer with an remainder of 0
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        num++;
}
```

for entering 60 you will output as

2
3
5

**Note you don't need count variable any more**

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha its the same as OP question just replace the loop by this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was just wondering how does it know when to stop at 5 and not go on to the other prime factors e.g 6,10,15 etc?

Comment: 6,10,15 are not prime.

Comment: Firstly 6 10 15 are not prime ... Secondly it doesn't stop at five it completes the entire loop till 60 as given in the example but it doesn't print those number as we have isPrime && integer % num == 0 to ensure that the num printed has to be prime and has to divide the integer with an remainder of 0. otherwise it won't be printed.

Comment: "for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++)" why is it "i<= num/2 " ?